# Why isn't my Blender FBX not appearing in XNA?

Tags: xna, blender, fbx

I am trying to display a simple cube in XNA. The cube is the default Blender cube exported to a `.fbx`. Re-exporting the cube has had no effect. I have also varied the camera's z-distance from 5 to 1000, to ensure the cube is not too small or too big. However, the cube does not display and I noticed that the `meshes.Count` is 0.

Would appreciate some advice.

This is the very basic code that draws the cube:

```
protected Vector3 cameraPosition = new Vector3(0f,0f, 10f);

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[cubeModel.Bones.Count];
            cubeModel.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in cubeModel.Meshes)
            {

                foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
                {
                    effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                    effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index];
                    effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, Vector3.Zero,
                       Vector3.Up);
                    effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
                       MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f), aspectRatio, 1.0f, 10000.0f);
                }

                mesh.Draw();
            }

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
```

Comment: Try checking the individual matrix values, maybe add them to the question. Try checking the model properties at runtime and make sure they are valid.

Comment: I think you need to actually apply the effect *pass*.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/22/effect-api-changes-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx

Comment: if your cube is larger that 10 units, then it is possible your camera is located inside the cube and the backfaces of the triangles are not being drawn. never mind, just re-read the original question